# List of checkboxes checked for specific classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get a list of names of which checkboxes are checked in a specific DIV (page-wrap).  I am creating a filter of sorts and have a treeview of different types like color, quality, grain, etc...  Each has its own class assigned to them.  Color has a class of color_cb, Quality is product_cb, Grain is grain_cb.  The following code works great for any one of them but I'd like to test for all 3.  Is there a way to modify this for all 3.

```
var selected = [];
    $('#page-wrap input:checkbox.color_cb:checked').each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
alert(selected.join(","));
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
var selected = [];
    $('#page-wrap input:checkbox.color_cb:checked input:checkbox.product_cb:checked').each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
alert(selected.join(","));
```

Comment: An easy rule of thumb is to remember jQuery selectors work much the same as CSS selectors. Write your selectors as if you were applying CSS  (e.g. you would put a comma between the different targets).

Comment: That is a great piece of information.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use comma separator b/w selected element

```
$('#page-wrap input:checkbox.color_cb:checked ,#page-wrap input:checkbox.product_cb:checked')
                                             ^^^^-- add , seperator
```

or use **[map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)**

```
var selected = $('#page-wrap input:checkbox.color_cb:checked ,#page-wrap input:checkbox.product_cb:checked').map(function () {
     return $(this).attr('name');
 }).get();
```

Comment: upvoting this instead of the removing class selector answer, as this creates a more strict selection incase there are other checkboxes that OP doesn't want to select. Alternatively, you can add a class to the checkboxes you want to include with the checkall function and select using that classname instead.

Comment: The comma separator worked perfectly but the option to use map() did not.

Comment: now check, you can use map as you was  used like each function

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the class should work fine.

```
var selected = [];
$('#page-wrap input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
alert(selected.join(","));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/60hnvnh9/1/

If there are checkboxes that you want to avoid targeting, simply give the checkboxes another, common class, and target that.

Answer (score 0):

```
'#page-wrap input:checkbox.color_cb:checked input:checkbox.product_cb:checked'
```

this query selector means that **input:checkbox.product_cb:checked** is child of **input:checkbox.color_cb:checked**

But, i think you are looking for elements that accomplish one OR the other query, for that you have to use a comma separator, like this:

```
'#page-wrap input:checkbox.color_cb:checked, #page-wrap input:checkbox.product_cb:checked'
```